# Angular 4 *ngFor current element value to increase and decrease

Tags: angular

I'm making a little application in Angular 4, I'm displaying a table with some data, I wanna increase and decrease the current value by clicking DecreaseVal() and IncreaseVal() function, but it change all the value in the loop.

```
<tr class="rem1" *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
   <td class="invert">
    <div class="quantity">
        <div class="quantity-select">
            <div class="entry minus" (click)="DecreaseVal()">&nbsp</div>
            <div class="entry value"><span>{{count}}</span></div>
            <div class="entry plus" (click)="IncreaseVal()">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is my component

```
 count=1;
    DecreaseVal()
    {
    this.count=this.count>1?this.count-1:this.count;
    }
    IncreaseVal()
    {
     this.count=this.count<5?this.count+1:this.count;
    }
```

Comment: `; let i=index`, you don't need to write this if you're not using the `i` variable.

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat yeah sure , i forget to remove that, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because your `count` variable is global and doesn't belong to the `Hero` class. You need to tweak you code in the following way:

Declare new field in
**hero.class.ts**

`count: number = 0;`

Tweak your template **component.html**

```
<tr class="rem1" *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
   <td class="invert">
    <div class="quantity">
        <div class="quantity-select">
            <div class="entry minus" (click)="DecreaseVal(hero)">&nbsp</div>
            <div class="entry value"><span>{{hero.count}}</span></div>
            <div class="entry plus" (click)="IncreaseVal(hero)">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And now in **component.ts**

```
DecreaseVal(hero: Hero)
{
    if (hero.count > 1) {
       hero.count--;
    }
}

IncreaseVal(hero: Hero)
{
    if (hero.count < 5) {
       hero.count++;
    }
}
```

UPD: Updated with suggestions and notes from Andrien Brunelat.

Comment: I feel like it would be much clearer to use `if` conditions instead of the `? :` syntax to chose whether or not you alter the value in the methods. (i.e. `if (hero.count > 1) { hero.count -= 1 }`)

Comment: Yeah! My bad :) Thanks for suggestions, I've updated my answer.

Comment: Adrien Brunelat and Vitalii Chmovzh, this logic working for me. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible solutions for your problem. First of all, it will increase all the values because is the same variable for all elements you are iterating. The first and quick solution is to add that count to your heroe object in your heroes array. Something like

`heroes = [{heroName:'example', count : 0}, {heroName:'other', count : 0}];`

Then, in your event you have to send the index to make the method know where to increase.

`(click)="IncreaseVal(i)"`

In your component then you have to increase the counter of that object.

`IncreaseVal(index){ this.heroes[index].count++; }`

The other solution is to create a child component for heroes. It will have the completed td and the counter val.

Comment: @ Jordy García , thanks for your suggestion , superb explanation , this answer is close to my query, but i should accept only one answer for this question.